# docker push Layer already exists invalid checksum digest format

Tags: docker, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline

When i push image to private register（harbor）：

```bash
$ docker push harbor.wxtest.com/public/alpine-delrediskline:3.16.0-3
The push refers to repository [harbor.wxtest.com/public/alpine-delrediskline]
887d6ad1c9d4: Layer already exists 
c7c486fce125: Layer already exists 
24302eb7d908: Layer already exists 
invalid checksum digest format
```

I tried to delete all images and then push again, the problem still exists.

This is docker info:

```bash
$ docker info
Client:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false

Server:
 Containers: 0
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 0
 Images: 5
 Server Version: 20.10.7
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
  userxattr: false
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Cgroup Version: 1
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: io.containerd.runc.v2 io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 
 runc version: 
 init version: 
 Security Options:
  apparmor
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 5.11.0-1020-aws
 Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 2
 Total Memory: 1.899GiB
 Name: weex-dev-lb
 ID: UX3F:6G5F:R67E:54QG:ZQGW:Y2PK:GMFA:SHI6:6EFA:VSDH:KAJP:UIUJ
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  harbor.phzt.weextest.com
  10.7.4.53:30002
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false

$ docker version
Client:
 Version:           20.10.7
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.13.8
 Git commit:        20.10.7-0ubuntu5~20.04.2
 Built:             Mon Nov  1 00:34:17 2021
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.7
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.8
  Git commit:       20.10.7-0ubuntu5~20.04.2
  Built:            Fri Oct 22 00:45:53 2021
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.5.9-0ubuntu1~20.04.4
  GitCommit:        
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.1-0ubuntu2~20.04.1
  GitCommit:        
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:
```

Below is a simple jenkinsfile：

```yaml
pipeline {
  agent {
    node {
      label 'go'
    }
  }
  stages {
      stage('构建并推送镜像') {
        agent none
        steps {
            sh '''cat > Dockerfile <<EOF
FROM nginx:latest
EOF
'''
          container('go') {
            sh 'docker build --network host -t harbor.wxtest.com/public/nginx-test:v1adfea .'
            withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId : 'harbor-new' ,passwordVariable : 'DOCKER_PASSWORD' ,usernameVariable : 'DOCKER_USERNAME' ,)]) {
              sh 'echo "asdfea342dfFD3" | docker login http://harbor.wxtest.com -u "admin" --password-stdin'
              sh 'docker push harbor.wxtest.com/public/nginx-test:v1adfea'
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

> This harbor is installed in Kubernetes through helm, and no certificate is configured; it needs to be used separately from the previous harbor (production environment).

I googled for a long time and didn't find a similar question, hope someone here can help me.

Answer (score 0):

The error status shown shows that the layer already exists if you have tried to remove all the available images and upload and it still is showing the status.
try creating a new repo and check by pushing the image there so that we can make confirmation about the values we provided by Jenkins file is valid and can be used to push accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,I tried to use the default `library` repo, and then re-tag, the problem is still the same

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It might be caused by one of the image layers(blob) corrupted in the file system. you could find and delete this blob and try repush